# What is the simplest way to return only the exceptions among two dataframes' columns?

Tags: python, pandas, macos, dataframe

A couple of things to lead off with:

1. `df1['Column x']` and `df2['Column x']` are ***not*** the same length, in my case **df2** is a number of rows longer than **df**.
2. `Column x` and `Column y` are both labeled `Player`, column values are objects (names)

EDIT: For example, data looks like this with many more rows and additional columns containing ints and floats, as well.

### df1

EDIT: CSV snippet

```
,Player,% Owned,+/-,GP,
0,Player1,3%,0%,0,
1,Player2,91%,0%,1,
2,Player3,99%,0%,1
```

### df2

```
,Player,% Owned,+/-,GP,
0,Player1,7%,8%,1,
1,Player2,94%,0%,0,
2,Player3,99%,0%,0,
3,Player4,57%,-0.3%,0,
4,Player5 0%,10%,1,
5,Player6,20%,50%,0
```

**

### Expected output:

**

| index | Player | % Owned | +/- | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Player4 | 57% | -0.3% | x |
| 4 | Player5 | 0% | 10% | y |
| 5 | Player6 | 20% | 50% | z |

**My expected output would be just the rows that exist in df2 and not in df2. I am simply looking for a solution that identifies or locates and returns the rows from df2 that contain a unique `Player` value; it needs to only look in `df2['Player']` for exceptions and ignore other columns.**

My dataframes are made up of NBA players' performance statistics/metric; **df1** is stats from 1st weeks of games and df2 is the next week of games, so there will inevitably be a handful of new players in the second week that did not play the first week, and so on and so forth.

My goal is to identify those players that are in **df2** but not appear in **df1**.

It seems pretty simple, but the solutions that I've come up with are clunky, and I'm sure there's a matter of fact way to do this.

Here's an example of the method I'm currently using.

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df2,df1], axis=0)

df_mask = (df_concat.assign(mask1=df_concat.duplicated('Player'), mask2=~concatenated.df_concat('Player', keep=False)))

df_expose = df_mask.loc[(df_mask['mask1'] == False) & (df_mask['mask2'] == True)]
```

'df_expose' contains the profiles I'm looking for, but I'm sure there's a better method.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your sample data as text, not as a picture or link, to make a [mcve] that we can test.

Comment: You can try an outer [join or merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html), or inverting a selection done with [isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: Here is a nice article on how to find the difference between two dataframes.  It includes the solution: df3 = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='right_only']. https://kanoki.org/2019/07/04/pandas-difference-between-two-dataframes/

Comment: @pakpe I've read through this article, only considers dfs of equal length unfortunately.

Comment: No. I tried the above method on your databases and it works fine.

Comment: The samples I posted were incorrect, but I changed them so they are accurate now. Tthe data I posted had matching categorical data in both sets, which should/would not be the case - 'Player' should be the only value that does not change from one week to the next. @pakpe

Comment: Post your expected output

Comment: Done, I appreciate your help here, I hope i explained my problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use merge function to get players in df2 only:

```
df1 = ['player' + str(i) for i in range(1,11)]
df2 = ['player' + str(i) for i in range(1,13)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)

df1.columns = ['Player']
df2.columns = ['Player']


#df1:                          #df2:   
   Player                      Player
0   player1                 0   player1
1   player2                 1   player2
2   player3                 2   player3
3   player4                 3   player4
4   player5                 4   player5
5   player6                 5   player6
6   player7                 6   player7
7   player8                 7   player8
8   player9                 8   player9
9   player10                9   player10
                            10  player11
                            11  player12

df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'outer', on=['Player'] ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='right_only']


#Result df:  

     Player      _merge
10  player11    right_only
11  player12    right_only
```

Comment: I just added sample CSV data to make it more closely resemble my source data. The major issue that I'm seeing with your solution is that it only works when the dataframes only column is '`Player` column. In reality where there are a ton of other columns with different datatypes, the solution you provided considers all of the indexes unique.

Comment: I changed the code by adding ```on = ['Player']``` Basically it works on the only players columns on both dataset.

Comment: This does in fact return the players only in df2, nice work. I should be able to then get their locations and drop them like so: 
`i = df2[(df2.Player == 'Player11')].index
ii = df2[(df2.Player == 'Player12')].index
df3 = df2.drop(i).drop(ii)`

Comment: Now to identify, locate, and drop these unique values so it has the same shape as df1.  I'd rather work with the df containing unique values but I've run into all sorts of errors trying to operate on dfs of different length

Comment: Use result df indexes: ```indx = df.index.tolist()``` then select from df2 like : ```df2.ix[indx]```